# How to use resource files in an Android Archive (aar) library?

Tags: android-layout, android-resources, android-library

I added an AAR to an app's project following [the standard procedure](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html). All Java classes of the library work flawlessly in the project.  I am trying to use drawable of the library in a layout file. To make sure the file is there, I opened to aar file and saw \"res\drawable\my_drawable.xml".
A layout file of the app has the following:

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:minHeight="120dp"
    android:maxWidth="10dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

Android Studio complains "Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/my_drawable'".

Could anyone offer a tip on how to use an AAR's resource file in a layout file?